# R: does R naturally preserve the order of rows

Tags: r, dataframe

When working with R, if you want to bring columns from a data frame into another data frame - is the row order preserved naturally?

Suppose I generate some random data, then split this data into a train set and a test. I make a random forest model on the train set, and then have the random forest predict on the test set. Now, I want the ID's from the original data inserted into the test results, so that I can have a method of tracing which observations were predicted correctly.

Here is some code I have written:

```
#load libraries
library(caret)
library(randomForest)

#generate data
property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,1000,15)
car_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,500,2)
other_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,100,30)

response <- c("approved","rejected")
response <- sample(response, 731, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))
response <- as.factor(response)

#make data frame
mydata = data.frame(property_damages_in_dollars, car_damages_in_dollars, other_damages_in_dollars, response)

#add ID
mydata$ID <- seq_along(mydata[,1])

#split data into train set and test set
index = createDataPartition(mydata$response, p=0.7, list = FALSE)
train = mydata[index,]
test = mydata[-index,]

#create random forest statistical model
rf = randomForest(response ~ property_damages_in_dollars + car_damages_in_dollars + other_damages_in_dollars, data=train, ntree=500, mtry=2)

#have the model predict the test set
pred = predict(rf, test, type = "prob")
labels = as.factor(ifelse(pred[,2]>0.5, "approved", "rejected"))
confusionMatrix(labels, test$response)

#manipulate the predicition frame
pred = data.frame(pred)
pred$what_model_predicted = labels
pred$truth = test$response

pred$prob = pmax(pred$approved, pred$rejected)

pred$val = ifelse(pred$what_model_predicted == pred$truth,1,0)

#this is the step I am not sure about - is it correct?
pred$id = test$ID
```

Could someone please tell if what I have done is correct?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that should be fine. You haven't done anything that adds/drops/reorders rows. (Also note that your last line is the second time you make that assumption - the first time is `pred$truth = test$response`.)

Comment: @Gregor: thank you! Can you explain your comment again please: last line is the second time you make that assumption - the first time is pred$truth = test$response)

Comment: Your last line you comment as *"this is the step I am not sure about - is it correct?"*. **Yes, it is correct.** But, if it wasn't correct, then your earlier line `pred$truth = test$response` would also not be correct. The earlier line is the first time you make the assumption that the rows are in the same order in `pred` as in `test`. The line you comment is the 2nd time you make that assumption.

Comment: Also, since it's in your question tags - `merge` is the one function that I've found unreliable about row orders. The `dplyr` join functions are much better. But I'm removing `dplyr`, SQL, and merge from your tags and title because you don't use any of them in the code you show.